# Automation hyperlink from title to relevant Wikipedia page

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing, automation

I would like to hyperlink any subsection to a relevant Wikipedia page while clicking on it. let's say that the name of the subsection is:

" Row and column vectors **(wiki)** "

when clicking on **(wiki)** lead to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row_and_column_vectors or even https://www.google.com/search?q=Row+and+column+vectors will work.

just wondering if someone knows a nice way to do it automatically, instead of hyperlinking each subsection one and one manually?

Comment: I have edited my answer a bit to make the result closer to your original question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a new command to add the link after the argument. In the MWE below I did not replace the spaces by underscores. Officially a space is not allowed in a URL, but most likely your pdf viewer and/or browser will automatically convert the spaces to the url encoding `%20`. Wikipedia then replaces `%20` with `_`.

To remove the **(wiki)** part from the Table of Contents and PDF bookmarks you can use the optional argument of `\subsection`, i.e., `\subsection[title in the toc]{full title with hyperlink}`.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\newcommand{\wikisubsection}[1]{\subsection[#1]{#1 \href{https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/#1}{\textbf{(wiki)}}}}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\wikisubsection{Row and column vectors}
\end{document}
```

Result (tooltip shows the link target):

[image]

Comment: Great answer! I didn't know about the automatic encoding conversion. By the way, to redefine section headings globally, one could add `\let\oldsubsection\subsection \renewcommand\subsection[1]{\oldsubsection{\wikititle{#1}}}`

Comment: @Quae I chose this solution because it's the simplest. However, since it violates the official specification for urls it may not work universally across viewers/browsers/OSes, especially older ones.

Comment: Future visitors: note that Quae's comment applies to an [earlier revision](https://tex.stackexchange.com/revisions/654788/1) of this answer.